# Customizing Sidebar Menu in Admin Panel Built with React and Refine.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, refinejs

I'm currently working on an admin panel for a news website using React, Refine . I'm relatively new to backend development, so I opted for Refine library to simplify the project.

my question might be irrelevant as I am a beginner,

in my project folder structure, specifically inside the "categories" directory, I've noticed that there's only a header component. However, I'd like to customize the sidebar menu, which toggles with a hamburger menu. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to locate the relevant code for this.

I want to update the UI of the current predefined sidebar with the Refine.js project's header and links. According to the tutorial I followed, this sidebar code should be in the "components" directory. However, when I check the "components" directory, I only see the header component.

I've attached a screenshot of the UI part I'm referring to for clarity. Can someone please guide me on where to find and customize the sidebar menu code within the Refine.js project?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In refine Next.js example we have wrapped pages with  which is a composition of header and sider components

Example of Next.js:
https://github.com/refinedev/refine/blob/next/examples/with-nextjs/pages/_app.tsx#L39

You can check the documentation for customizing parts of the layout
https://refine.dev/docs/api-reference/mui/components/mui-themed-layout/

Answer (score 1):

in the latest app create by refine mostly code is present inside node_modules/@refinedev folder

Once you know the UI framework, explore the corresponding component directory within your project structure. Here are the typical locations for each framework:

Ant Design: @refinedev/antd/src/components/layout/Sider

Chakra UI: @refinedev/chakra-ui/src/components/layout/Sider

Material UI: @refinedev/material-ui/src/components/layout/Sider

Tailwind CSS: @refinedev/tailwind-ui/src/components/layout/Sider